# Ruby on Rails create_table (SQlite3 vs PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, sqlite

I recently made the leap from SQlite3 to PostgreSQL for compatibility with Heroku. Apon researching I noticed there are differences in datatypes across each and I really don't want to mess anything up. I was wondering how I could make the following migration compatible with PostgreSQL? My Gemfile is running `gem 'pg'` now instead of `gem SQlite3`.

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :summary
      t.string :thumbnail_link
      t.text :body
      t.integer :blog_category_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Does rails automatically convert everything when I run the migration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, just go ahead and run `rails db:migrate` on your local machine, but if it's already on Heroku run `heroku run rails db:migrate`. remember to change your database settings in `config/database.yml`before doing so. Cheers!